# Problem with 'rigid type variable' in a Monad in haskell

Tags: haskell, monads

I'm trying to learn monads better and am playing around with it in Haskell. I defined a monad in this way:

```
module TESTMonad where

import Control.Monad

newtype TEST i = TEST {getTEST :: ((i, Int), Int)} deriving (Show, Eq, Ord)

instance Functor TEST where
    fmap f (TEST ((x,y), z)) = TEST ((f x, y), z)

instance Applicative TEST where
    pure = return
    tf <*> tx = tf >>= \f -> tx >>= \x -> return (f x)

instance Monad TEST where
    return x = TEST ((x, 1), 1)
    (TEST ((x, y), z)) >>= f = TEST ((plusOne a, b), c)
        where
                ((a, b), c) = getTEST (f x)

plusOne :: Int -> Int
plusOne x = x+1
```

but I get the following error when I'm trying to compile it:

```
TESTMonad.hs:16:47: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘Int’ with actual type ‘b’
      ‘b’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
          (>>=) :: forall a b. TEST a -> (a -> TEST b) -> TEST b
        at TESTMonad.hs:16:24
    • In the first argument of ‘plusOne’, namely ‘a’
      In the expression: plusOne a
      In the expression: (plusOne a, b)
    • Relevant bindings include
        a :: b (bound at TESTMonad.hs:18:19)
        f :: a -> TEST b (bound at TESTMonad.hs:16:28)
        (>>=) :: TEST a -> (a -> TEST b) -> TEST b
          (bound at TESTMonad.hs:16:5)
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

I clearly know that I might be doing lots of things in the wrong way but I have no idea what are they. Any comment would be appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: What makes you think the `a` in your implementation must be an `Int`? `plusOne` only takes an `Int` as argument.

Comment: In other words, your `Monad` instance must work with *any* type, but your definition uses `plusOne` which requires it to be an `Int`. Even relaxing it to `plusOne :: Num a => a -> a` would still be too restrictive for your `Monad` instance.

Comment: @Robin Zigmond True, but what if I want it to be "Int "? How am I supposed to define the monad TEST and type "TEST i" in that case?

Comment: @chepner Yes I 've tried that before and it didn't work. What should I do if I want the monad to only accept "Int" and make its type a bit more specific?

Comment: You can't; what you describe is not a `Monad`.

Comment: Inside the definition of `(>>=)`, you have *no idea* what the type of `a` might be, so you can do very little with `a`.

Comment: @chepner Ah, I see! So, it might no be a monad. Interesting!

Comment: It *can* be a monad; just your *definiition* of `(>>=)` is wrong. `... = TEST ((a, b), c) where ...` is fine.

Answer (score 1):

The `Monad` instance cannot be constrained. The type of `(>>=)` must be

```
Monad m => m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
```

but your definition, using `plusOne :: Int -> Int`, makes the type

```
Monad m => m Int -> (Int -> m Int) -> m Int
```

You could safely apply `plusOne` to either of the other values wrapped inside `TEST`, as they are already defined to be `Int`s.

The definition of `(>>=)` has no idea what the type of `x` might be, and the caller gets to choose `f`, so it has no idea what the type of `f x` might either. As a result, you can't really do anything with it except use it as-is.

Comment: But this typing does not work as the type of the ``` <*> ``` in Applicative is ``` (<*>) :: f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b ``` !

Comment: Note that one of the [`Applicative` laws](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Applicative_functors#Applicative_functor_laws) is `pure id <*> v == v`. This means you must preserve the "context" of the right-hand argument. In other words, `TEST ((f, _), _) <*> TEST ((x, y), z) == TEST ((f x), y, z)`. Paired with `pure x = TEST ((x, 1, 1)`, I *think* this constitutes a valid `Applicative` instance; I'll leave it as an exercise to verify this definition satisfies the other three.